# impossible to unmount a truecrypt partition after accessing it via samba

Tags: samba, truecrypt, unmount

I am using a true-crypt partition, which is mounted inside a samba share.

This works as expected, until I access a folder inside the archive from windows via samba. After this it's impossible to unmount the partition even after rebooting the windows machine (and closing everything accessing that partition on the host machine too).

Currently my only recourse is to reboot the host machine. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Check with `smbstatus` if Samba has any open files on that share and provide the output, please.

Comment: Did you open it using a terminal?

Comment: drc: thanks for the comment, I'm not sure what's changed but if the problem occurs again that will be of great use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it appears that the problem has gone away.